# Finding recursively all the possible combinations of k elements of an array, where k is the last element of the array

Tags: java, recursion

The assignment was the following. I do think the text is flawed and I'll explain why subsequently:

> Write a recursive method `comb` which, given an integer k and arbitrarily many integer parameters, returns all the combinations of k elements.
> For example, `comb(2, 1, 1, 2, 3)` returns a list of the following sets: `{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1},  {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 2}`.

Now, I find two problems. Those are not sets, as they contain duplicate elements. As a result, I had my method return a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Furthermore, the example of an output given is misleading because neither it excludes combinations with the same elements, nor it includes *all* possible combinations.
Am I correct in concluding this?

Anyway, I thought I would return *all* possible combinations. Here is my solution, I would like to know if a simpler one is possible. `k` being one of the many parameters made it harder, if the parameters were a List *and* `k` it'd be straightforward.

```
public List<List<Integer>> comb(Integer... params) 
{
    int length = params.length;
    int k = params[params.length-1];
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(params);
    Set<Integer> integersSet = Set.copyOf(integers);
    
    if (k == 1) 
    {
        return integers.stream().distinct().map(List::of).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    Integer[] prevParams = new Integer[length];
    prevParams = Arrays.copyOf(params, length);
    prevParams[length-1] = k-1;
    
    Set<List<Integer>> toBeAdded = new HashSet<>();
    Set<List<Integer>> toBeRemoved = new HashSet<>();
    
    List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(prevParams));
    tempList.add(0, k);
    Integer[] tempArray = tempList.toArray(new Integer[tempArray.size()]);
    Set<List<Integer>> result = Set.copyOf(comb(tempArray)); 
    
    for (Integer integer : integersSet) 
    {
        for (List<Integer> l : result) 
        {   List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(List.of(integer)); 
            temp.addAll(l); 
            toAdd.add(temp);
        }
    }

    result = toBeAdded;
    
    for (Integer integer : integersSet) 
    {
        result.removeIf(e -> Collections.frequency(e, integer) > Collections.frequency(integers, integer));
    
        for (List<Integer> l : result)
        {
            Set<Integer> setDifference = new HashSet<>(l);
            setDifference.removeAll(integersSet);
            if (!setDifference.isEmpty() || l.size() == k-1) toBeRemoved.add(l);
        }
    }

    result.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
    return List.copyOf(result);
}
```

Comment: Yes. There are simpler solution. First you can introduce new method to avoid passing k as part of array.

Comment: Based on the task description, I'd assume that in `comb(2, 1, 1, 2, 3)` call the first number is `k`, so `k==2`. However, that doesn't align with the example output. If all parameters are used as parameters to be used for creating the output, then how is `k` passed? And just like you, I can't think of any way that those are all possible outputs for the example input. So basicly that is a flawed task that can't be solved.

Comment: @talex: Do you mean having another method which takes an array and then k? That's indeed easy, but if you try it you'll see the results are different if the conversion is "naive". In other words, say the other method is `combA` and `arrayA` is the array of the "non-k-parameters" (all but the last one) - one can see that the output of `comb(params)` is different from the one of `combA(arrayA, k)`. Of course this can be amended, but it seems to me the logic would have to be similar to mine.

Comment: @Amongalen: Yes, if `k` were the first number, it would be easy because it could be separated from the other numbers, something like `comb(int k, Integer... params)`. As for passing `k`: if you try my code, you can see that it does work. So I do manage to pass `k`, it's just that I need to make considerable adjustments as can be seen, hence I was wondering if one could do better, more smoothly.

Comment: The problem description is using the word "sets" in the mathematical sense, not the computer sense.  The entire collection is a set because each triplet is a unique instance, not that the individual numbers are unique.  I don't think the set of triplets in the problem description was meant to be a complete set.  The problem statement could have been written better,  but it's basically, "create all non-duplicated permutations of k numbers from a set of n numbers".

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: But even in the mathematical sense, a set cannot have duplicate elements, so I don't see how `{1,1,2}` and the others can be "sets". The entire collection may as well be a set, but the problem description does use the word "list" and not a generic word, so it's safe to assume the entire collection is a `List`. //  "I don't think the set of triplets in the problem description was meant to be a complete set" : do you mean that the given "sets" were just a handful of the ones to be returned? Maybe, but then, since it reads "a list of the following sets", it's very poorly written.

Comment: @Learner: {1,1,2} is one element of a set of triplets. {1,2,1} is another element of a set of triplets.  The two examples are different elements of a set, even though the numbers are the same.  "List" in the problem description is a generic word, and not necessarily referring to a Java List.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: No, in the problem description {1, 1, 2} is called a set: "... returns a list of the following sets...".